# selecting from multiple elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change this JavaScript code into jQuery, but I'm not sure what the equivalent of using `onClick = 'function(this)'` with jQuery's `.click` function.

JavaScript:

```
function setInput(text) {

   var getClicked = text.name;
   var  click = document.getElementById(getClicked);
   var  show = document.getElementById('show_' + getClicked);

   show.value = click.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name = "a" id = "a" onclick='setInput(this);'>
<input type = "text" id = "show_a"><br>
<input type='text' name = "b" id = "b" onclick='setInput(this);'>
<input type = "text" id = "show_b">
```

Comment: If you don't know how to write jQuery, then you need to *learn* jQuery. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials ... http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Show what you have tried. And what is your question? Did you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Why would you use jQuery if you already have working vanilla javascript code?

Comment: I am trying to learn jquery so its a learning process really

Comment: Learning involves reading through tutorials and docs to understand how it works. What you're doing is just asking for a solution without having to go through the effort of learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('click', function(){
  $('#show_' + $(this).attr('name')).val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the inputs already exist in the DOM, the following will work.

```
$('#a, #b').click(function () {
    setInput(this);
});
```

Otherwise, try

```
$(function() {
    $('#a, #b').click(function () {
        setInput(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input class="clickme" type="text" name ="a" id ="a">
   <input type ="text" id ="show_a"><br>
<input class="clickme"  type="text" name ="b" id ="b">
   <input type ="text" id ="show_b">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        id = "#show_";
        id += $(this).prop("id");
        $(id).show();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTtHT/1/

Comment: thank you for the post and jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses CSS selectors to access elements in the DOM. If you give these input elements a classname, like "settable", you can add the behaviour:

```
$(".settable").click(function(e){
    var getClicked = $(this).attr('name');
    ...
});
```

Where $(this) refers to the element that has been clicked.